# Need steps to implement facebook payment in my unity game

Tags: facebook-graph-api, payment, facebook-unity-sdk

I made a game for Facebook canvas in unity, Now i want to sell items in my game with Facebook payment, The problem is i am not a good programmer and Facebook documentations are very hard to understand, so i need some simple steps to integrate payment to my game,

i registered Facebook payment company,

Now how to define product in my unity codes?

How to prompt dialog box?

what to write in callback URL in php?

please make it simple and clear for me 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to investigate a bit more on how to achieve this, since there is a lot of information available. I'll try to clear some doubts of yours:

- To define products for your game, you need to define an [Open Graph Object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/), and upload it to a server (can be your own, or dropbox). [Here is a guide from my blog](http://blog.bigfootgaming.net/integrating-facebook-achievements-in-unity3d/), where I teach how to upload and host OG Objects for achievements, steps are similar.
- The in-game code to use in Unity is the method Pay ([FB.Canvas.Pay](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Canvas.Pay/)), which receives the url of your hosted OG Object, and some other parameters, and it prompts the user with the appropiate interface to pay (Keep in mind this only works when the game is inside the facebook canvas)

I Hope this starts to guide you on how to approach the paymet system!

I'll answer the questions in the comment here:

- No, you don't need the Javascript SDK anymore. Just need to have the Unity SDK in your game.
- I haven't found much information on the callback, but since I don't really use it, I just used this code inside a PHP script to just make it work:

  $hub_mode = $_GET['hub_mode'];

  $hub_challenge = $_GET['hub_challenge'];

  $hub_verify_token = $_GET['hub_verify_token'];

  if ($hub_verify_token =='YourToken')

  {

  echo $hub_challenge;

  }

Comment: thanks to clear these point but i need two more things to be clear.
1.am i need javascript sdk anymore to prompt pay dialog or for other?
2.What to write in callback.php URL ? in realtime update i will use static pricing for five objects.

Comment: Do you want me to guess what those 2 are :P ?

Comment: now check my question. :P i entered and comment was posted

Comment: Ok just one more thing then i choose your answer as correct :)
I see on another question that we dont need calback url in static pricing callback only required in dynamic pricing is it right? and should i leave callback field blank in apps dashboard?